# MySQLでテーブル作成時、Incorrect table definition エラーになる

Tags: mysql, sql, database

### testというDBにorg_categoryというテーブルを追加したい

MySQLを起動して以下のコードでテーブルを作成しようとした

```
CREATE TABLE test.org_category (
    category_id INT(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'カテゴリID',
    name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COMMENT '名前',
    url VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COMMENT 'URL',
    create_date timestamp not null default current_timestamp COMMENT '作成日',
    `update-date` timestamp not null default current_timestamp COMMENT '更新日'
);
```

しかし、

```
ERROR 1293 (HY000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

というエラーが出てしまい失敗。

原因を調べてみたところ以下のような記事を発見した
https://runble1.com/mysql-current-timestamp/

timestampがどうやら原因のようだが、対処法が分からなかったので質問させて頂きました。

よければ教えていただけると光栄です。

Comment: mysqlのバージョンは何ですか？バージョンによっては１テーブ１カラムしか使えないようです。

Comment: 参照記事およびさらにその参考記事に答えがそのまま書いてあるようですが、それだと何か要求に満たないのでしょうか？

Comment: すいません。訂正します。timestampではなくdatetimeでした。。。もう一度調べ直します。